# iOS openurl for multiple files

Tags: ios, openurl

I have written like this to accept exported files from other application.

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
           openURL:(NSURL *)url
 sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
        annotation:(id)annotation {
    if (url != nil && [url isFileURL])
    {            
        NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *docPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *filePath = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[self.arrayGetSplit objectAtIndex:counting] ];

        [myData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];           
    }
    return YES;
}
```

But I can only save 1 file. How can I support for multiple files if users export multiple files?

Comment: Refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20848913/how-to-handle-uiapplication-handleopenurl-with-multiple-urls

Comment: it is for facebook, instagram. But my case is for file sharing between 2 app.

Comment: Any solution to this issue? I've got the same.